# Docker Hello-world fails with "no such file or directory"

Tags: docker

OS: Ubuntu cinammon 20.04

I followed the directions from here: [docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/)

When I get to the step to run the Hello-world image.

`$ sudo docker run hello-world docker: Error response from daemon: open /var/lib/docker/aufs/layers/9cd449051217b6dc5c24c81e1a02ef897eeb90ee62421d6a227ddfbeddc2b70c-init: no such file or directory. See 'docker run --help'.`

`

I've stopped and started the daemon.
`sudo service docker stop sudo service docker start`

and

`systemctl restart docker`

The image exists locally per:
`$ sudo docker images REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE hello-world         latest              bf756fb1ae65        6 months ago        13.3kB`

I've been Googling this and getting nowhere. I've seen other places where restarting the daemon fixes it, but I'm just not that lucky.

Any ideas??

More info:

```
$ sudo docker version
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           19.03.12
 API version:       1.40
 Go version:        go1.13.10
 Git commit:        48a66213fe
 Built:             Mon Jun 22 15:45:44 2020
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          19.03.12
  API version:      1.40 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.13.10
  Git commit:       48a66213fe
  Built:            Mon Jun 22 15:44:15 2020
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.2.13
  GitCommit:        7ad184331fa3e55e52b890ea95e65ba581ae3429
 runc:
  Version:          1.0.0-rc10
  GitCommit:        dc9208a3303feef5b3839f4323d9beb36df0a9dd
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.18.0
  GitCommit:        fec3683
```

Comment: `docker system prune` run this command, seem directory courpted but this command will clear everything!

Comment: Thanks, but `docker system prune` did not work for me.